# Unable to switch account in "NET USE" command under SQL SERVER AGENT

Tags: sql-server, networking, sharepoint, ssis, database-administration

Our team is working on an SSIS package in which we need to access a SharePoint library to read Excel files. At very beginning of the package we are using an Execute Process Task to execute

```
Net Use \\sharepoint\DataDrop password /User:Domain\user1 /PERSISTENT:Yes
```

command to map network drive, everything is working well in BIDS, we are able to map or delete the mapping.

However, after we deploying the package under SQL SERVER AGENT and test running it for the first time and would like to use another account user2 and run it again we get error below:

```
Net Use \\sharepoint\DataDrop password /User:Domain\user2 /PERSISTENT:Yes

System error 1219 has occurred.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.
```

I was thinking executing `Net Use \\sharepoint\DataDrop /delete` in a prior step would solve the problem but but we get another error saying

```
The network connection could not be found.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

Final thing is if we put `NET USE DELETE` task in the SSIS package right after the first `Net Use \\sharepoint\DataDrop password /User:Domain\user1 /PERSISTENT:Yes` we do not get any errors.

Simply speaking, after we using user1 under SQL SERVER AGENT we cannot find a way to switch to user2.

Does anyone know the solution here?

Comment: Why it has been tagged with Powershell? I am removing that